# click в jquery возвращает нативный js объект

Tags: javascript, jquery

при клике на ссылку должен вызываться jquery объект:

`$( ".__tab-btn" ).click(function() {
    console.log(this);
});`

но выводится нативный объект!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть так: `$( this ).addClass( 'class' );` я уже не могу написать, выдаст ошибку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объект jQuery это массивоподобная обертка над элементами DOM, поэтому объект this в области видимости функции click, является элементом DOM (JS объект HTMLElement, оный является интерфейсом для любого HTML элемента) на котором сработало событие клика. jQuery умеет оборачивать DOM элементы, а значит в рамках функции код

```
$(this).addClass('class');
```

вполне рабочий и ошибки быть не может.

Comment: отлично. Через `.each()` вытащил нужные значения, благодарю за напоминание